# Hibernate: test existence of a FK

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I have an object Object that is linked to AnotherObject with a manyToOne relationship. So the table hosting Object has a fk to AnotherObject.

Now, from Java, I want to check if the relationship exists with

```
object.getAnotherObject.getId() != null
```

Thus this will request the full AnotherObject, which is totally un-necessary there. Avoid to avoid this and check check if the FK exists?

My configuration:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idanotherobject")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@BatchSize(size=15)
private AnotherObject anotherObject;
```

Comment: I also have the same problem with linked object in a OneToOne relationship, but the relation is defined in the other part : @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "stillAnother")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) . How to only test the existence of the linked object without queriing it fully?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to double check from your Java code that the SQL constraint is working?

Comment: State the need of doing so. Further, if the column holding the foreign key allows a `null` value, then the conditional test will fail with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, when a child with a `null` parent is attempted.

Comment: Not testing the SQL constraint, I need to know if an instance of Object has a link to AnotherObject without requesting the full AnotherObject

Comment: Depending upon the need, there could be another better way of simulating the same which can only be determined, if you state why checking the existence of a relationship is essentially needed.

Comment: Well, from Java, I iterate over many (up to 2000) instances of Object and I set a boolean whether there is a link to AnotherObject. As the FK is defined in Object, each time I check the link, Hibernate queries the related AnotherObject and mounts it in an object, whereas from an SQL point of view this is not necessary

Comment: This `object.getAnotherObject() != null` should do. This `object.getAnotherObject()` returns an uninitialized proxy instance, if `FetchType` is set to `LAZY`. This proxy instance will get populated fully, if any non-key field is attempted (the behaviour could be provider specific) which issues a query to the database to fetch the row corresponding to the entity's `id`.